# To host CPTGraph inside NSScrollView

Tags: core-plot, nsscrollview

How to plot more plot points in CPTGraph. I want to implement it using NSScrollView. But there is no delegate methods for checking the "scrolling".

Please give me some suggestions for implementing the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have to use a scroll view? Core Plot natively supports scrolling. Just set `allowsUserInteraction` to `YES` on the plot space. You can set the `globalXRange` and/or `globalYRange` to limit the scrolling range. You can also use a plot space delegate to monitor the scrolling and exert more control over the scrolling behavior or perform other actions.

Comment: Hi Eric.Thanks for Your valuable reply